# Javascript - Tilemap click on tile

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to get the x y coordinates of the tile that I click, on as well as its location/index in the array ("map.tiles").

Create tilemap:

```
var map = {
    cols: 8,
    rows: 8,
    tsize: 100,
    tiles: [
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,
        0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
    ],
    solidTiles : [1,2],

    getTile: function(col,row) {
        return this.tiles[row * map.cols + col]
    }
}
```

Define mouse x and y

```
mouseX = e.pageX-c.offsetLeft; //get mouse's x position
mouseY = e.pageY-c.offsetTop;
```

Render tile map:

```
for(let c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
    for(let r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        var tile = map.getTile(c,r);
        if(tile != 0) { //not an empty tile
            renderSheet(
                "tiles.png", //spritesheet
                (tile-1) * map.tsize, //tile index * tilesize
                0, //tile y index
                map.tsize, //tile width
                map.tsize, //tile height
                c * map.tsize, //tile x
                r* map.tsize, //tile y
                map.tsize, //tile width
                map.tsize //tile height
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Please help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is divide the mouse x & y with the tile size to get the tile id then multiply it by the tilesize again to get the tile x & y

```
player.x = Math.floor(mouseX/map.tsize)*map.tsize;
player.y = Math.floor(mouseY/map.tsize)*map.tsize;
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :D

Comment: Man, I had to struggle a lot, until I found my login and password to vote your answer. This is a great solution, and it deserves more votes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that constantly checks if any tiles x and y  overlap with the mouse x and y.

Output the array index currently overlapping when the mouse click event is detected.

```js
function overlapping() {
  for(i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
    if (mouseX > tile[i].x && mouseX < tile[i].x + tile[i].width) {
      if (mouseY > tile[i].y && mouseY < tile[i].y + tile[i].height) {
        return i;  
      }
    }
  }
  overlapping();
}
```

Comment: Did it fix the issue?